# Ionic 6 Angular theme always dark on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I am using Ionic 6 / Angular.

I have noticed that in `variables.scss` contains:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  ...
}
```

The issue is that unless I rename dark to for example:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark-off) {
  ...
}
```

In Android phones the mode is always dark in display, no matter if I select light or dark, it's always dark.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a light theme, then you can comment out the dark mode css in `variables.scss`. It is not always dark mode, it will follow the default theme that your android device is using. I guess your device is on dark mode, try to change it to light mode and you will see it turn to light mode.

Comment: I actually want to have both modes, which works great in IOS but Android just gives me dark always unless I comment out dark mode :(

Comment: Are you testing it using an emulator or a real device? If you are using a real device, then what is the theme set on your device?

Comment: Both the emulator and the real device